# Convert DateComponent to Int

Tags: ios, swift

To get the difference between two dates in days I did the following:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
guard let startDate = timeStartDate else { return }
let pastTime = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: Date())
```

Now I'm trying to calculate something with `pastTime` hence I need the `Int`. How can I convert a value of type `DateComponent` to `Int`?

So far using `Int(pastTime)` I got the following error:

> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'DateComponents' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Answer (score 4):

`pastTime` is of type `DateComponents` and thus it can't be passed as a parameter to the `Int` initializer.

Use the [`.day`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents/1779808-day) property of `DateComponents`:

```
let numberOfDays = pastTime.day
```

Which is an optional `Int`, but since you've specified the `day` component in `dateComponents:from:to`, you could safely unwrap it as noted by @vadian:

```
let numberOfDays = pastTime.day!
```

Comment: If you specify any component in `dateComponents:from:to`, the corresponding property will never be `nil`. That's one of the few cases where force unwrapping is 100% safe.